# How to ensure that github recongizes the changes done to a local, git cloned branch even after the workspace is closed and re-opened?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I git cloned this branch

```
https://github.com/cnvrg/anomaly-detection.git
```

in a workspace (jupyter notebook, temrinal session)

I received some files and then did some changes in those files (changed syntax and documentation in .py/.md files)

Now, If i continue to work in the same workspace and push the changes using these steps below

```
[git add .
git commit -m "edited readme files"
git remote add origin https://github.com/cnvrg/text-summarization
git push -u origin master]
```

it works flawlessly.

However, If i somehow close the workspace and then re-open it, and do git status, it shows "its not a git directory".
Then if I do git init, and then repeat the same steps, it git doesn't recognize that the code came from the same remote repo and even if the new code is pushed, it shows everything to be in green/red while comparing.

Is there some way, (git pull changes or some other method) that I can use to ensure that if I re-open my workspace, I can ensure that git sees that my repo is pulled from the remote repo

```
https://github.com/cnvrg/anomaly-detection.git
```

and is not a fresh code?

Thanks

I tried to ensure that even after my workspace is closed and re-opened, git recognizes only my changes and doesn't treat the code as new one.
I tried
git stash
git branch -track
git push set upstream

nothing worked.

Comment: Are you standing on the same directory you worked on before?

Comment: As eftshift0 starts to get at, you aren't providing much information for us to go on. There's myriad ways to be using Jupyter and you don't describe where you are using it at all. We don't know what you mean by close the workspace. It almost sounds like you are working in a namespace that's getting shut down and so the new one has no memory of what you did. You'd want to be working in a persistent terminal on your machine, for example with Anaconda/conda you'd activate the environment in your machine's terminal and work and close out. And later and come back and do the same to activate & work.

Comment: <continued> However, because you described very little of your own set up here, it's hard to provide much guidance.